# angular 4 reactive form group validation

Tags: angular, validation, angular-reactive-forms

i need advice! I want validate reactive form.
I have two form groups and both have input with same formcontrolname.

**my code:**

```
  this.form = this.fb.group({
  group1: this.fb.group({
    name: ['', Validators.required],
  }),
  group2: this.fb.group({
    name: [ '', Validators.required],
  })
});
```

How cen i get both of name?

I tried this. But i dont know which one i get.

```
get name() { return this.form.get('name'); }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just used this statement, it should work : )

```
get name() { return this.form.get('group1.name').value; }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534244/form-validation-is-not-working-in-angular

Answer (score 0):

With such structure:

```
this.form = formBuilder.group({
'varA': [],
'varB': formBuilder.group({
  'varC': []
(...)
```

Accessing looks like this:

```
varA = this.form.value['varA']
varC = this.form.value['varB']['varC'];
```

If I got your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function in component

```
 get name() { 
       return this.form.controls['group1'].value.name;
    }
```

Comment: help needed on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49534244/form-validation-is-not-working-in-angular